# For loop Does not start

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

I just started learning web development and decided to make a simple apache cordova app, but for some reason my for loop does not start.

index.js:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

renderList();

function renderList()
{
    console.log("renderlist")
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log("for loop")
    }
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    //default apache cordova stuff
};
```

in javascript console i only get "renderlist", but no "for loop" or "end"

Comment: `"use strict"` is enabled so you cannot use a variable without defining it by `var` or `let`

Comment: Thank you, got it working  `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare i.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```